# I can't install kivy on windows. Command line returns traceback erorr

Tags: python, pip, kivy

I want to install Kivy. I followed the instruction from their official website: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html .
In the instructions it says to open the command line and to ensure that you have the latest pip, wheel, and virtualenv: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv`. I wrote this command and got the following traceback.

I have win 10 32bit 
Python Version - Python 3.6.5

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2016. Все права защищены.

C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3'

C:\Windows\system32>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is not a help-desk; drop the "HELP ME TO RESOLVE THIS PROBLEM" and "So, please, help me!!!!". That's not how SO works.

Comment: @roganjosh any pointers for OP to get out of the bush quickly? Perhaps a tutorial we can't google ;p

Comment: ..can imagin you install something that is called ... `pip._vendor.urllib3` or `urllib3`... via a `pip search ...`

Comment: @ZF007 I fixed the formatting for them in a single pass, I'm sure sure there are other changes to be made. This question isn't in my domain to help with so I can't answer.

Comment: [Installing pip from scratch](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) might help if your pip is too old but you'd better upgrade your whole python if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try to run
pip3 install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools virtualenv

pip3 install kivy==1.11.1